# A float hack doesn't make the scrollbars appear..?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a website with a few `<div>`s set up similar to this example http://jsfiddle.net/kLQ5z/1/

The problem is that if a visitor has a small screen, the `outerContent` will be off-screen.
Normally, scrollbars would appear, but because I've set the `<div>`s up in such a hack-ish way, they don't appear, and you can't even use your mouse's horizontal scroll.

Any help?

Comment: What browser are you experiencing this problem on? The scrollbars show up just fine for me on your JSFiddle using Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that the JSFiddle actually DOES display the scrollbars.. :/  I'm using the version 17.0.1 of Firefox. I'll try to see if the problem is caused by the difference between my actual code and the code I wrote in the JSFiddle, or in the fact that I'm actually using JSFiddle. Brb.

Comment: Hmm, OK, so what are your constraints? How much of the HTML structure can you change? I assume you want the big box to be exactly centered, if there's room for both it and the small box, right?

Comment: Well, yeah, I want the bigger box to be centered. I'm not really sure about how much of the code I can change, I'll have to fiddle around with my code anyways when I get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with your jsFiddle, and [here's something that seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/RZzEV/1/).  Basically, what I used was an iterative process:

1. To make scroll bars appear when the floating box goes off screen, it has to lie within the content area.
2. One way to do that is to give the main box a fixed left margin, but to keep it centered, we then need to wrap it in an outer div with `margin: auto`.
3. To keep it *exactly* centered, we also need to give it a matching right margin.
4. But ideally, if the screen is too narrow to show it fully, we'd like that margin to be squeezed out before any scrollbars appear.  What works like that in CSS?  Table cells!  So instead of a fixed margin, we use an empty dummy div with `display: table-cell`.

It's still a hack, and I'd be surprised if it couldn't be improved.  Nor have I tested it very well, but it seems to work on Chrome at least.

Comment: Nevermind the last comment. Easily fixed by using a margin-right. Thanks.